# Setting a UICollectionView Cell Height In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a UICollectionView which each cell will have a different height based on the amount of content in the cell. I am understanding that

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

is called to set the individual cell size when the cell is dequeued. I am working out the height that the cell needs to be in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

but the variables I create are not being preserved in sizeForItemAtIndexPath.

Where am I going wrong? The complete class is below. I have been messing around  trying to get this to work so there may be some unnecessary code floating around. Any help is grateful received.

```
import UIKit
var cellHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    internal var thisCellHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height


        var thisWidth = screenWidth - 10

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: thisWidth, height: 180)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        //collectionView!.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor("#15ADFF")
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 14
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        println("Index Path Number: \(indexPath)")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        var typeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, 200, 21))
        typeLabel.text = "Card Type"
        typeLabel.font = typeLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
        cell.addSubview(typeLabel)

        var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 25, 250, 21))

        titleLabel.text = "This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title."
        titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        thisCellHeight = CGFloat(titleLabel.frame.height)
        println("The title text is \(cellHeight) high")
        cell.addSubview(titleLabel)

        var authorLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, thisCellHeight + 30, 200, 21))
        authorLabel.text = "This Is The Article Author"
        authorLabel.font = authorLabel.font.fontWithSize(15)
        cellHeight = cellHeight + CGFloat(authorLabel.frame.height)
        println("After article added height \(cellHeight) high")
        cell.addSubview(authorLabel)

        var timestampLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, thisCellHeight + 50, 200, 21))
        timestampLabel.text = "This Is The Timestamp"
        timestampLabel.font = timestampLabel.font.fontWithSize(15)
        cellHeight = cellHeight + CGFloat(timestampLabel.frame.height)
        println("After timestamp added height \(cellHeight) high")
        cell.addSubview(timestampLabel)

        return cell
    }

    func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet() as NSCharacterSet).uppercaseString

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = cString.substringFromIndex(advance(cString.startIndex, 1))
        }

        if (countElements(cString) != 6) {
            return UIColor.grayColor()
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        NSScanner(string: cString).scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {



        println("Passed height = \(cellHeight)")

        return CGSizeMake(270, 300)


    }



}
```

Comment: Where you're going wrong is trying to figure out the cell height in cellForItemAtIndexPath. You should do it in sizeForItemAtIndexPath, just like you would do it in heightForRowAtIndexPath in a table view. Your code in cellForItemAtIndexPath is not good either, as you will be adding all those labels multiple times when the cell is reused. You should add all the labels in the init method of a custom cell class instead.